# How to use ruby .map to add quotes to array elements

Tags: sql, ruby, arrays, sorting, dictionary

**See my example below where I put 'something' I'm just confused on what to map:**

```
array_ids = ['1','2']

array = array_ids.map(something).join(',')
```

So when I do:

```
order_sql = "FIELD(ID,#{array})"
```

I get this:

```
order_sql = "FIELD(ID,'1','2')"
```

Comment: `array` is perhaps not the best name for a string. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
array_ids = ['1','2']

array = array_ids.map { |id| "'#{id}'" }.join(',')

p array
# => "'1','2'"

order_sql = "FIELD(ID,#{array})"

p order_sql
# => "FIELD(ID,'1','2')"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome thank you, i think I was overthinking this, and thought it had to be shorter!